# Expedia Bargain Fare: can you cancel within 24 hours?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, cancellations, expedia

If I book a flight selecting the Expedia Bargain Fare, what are the cancellation conditions? In particular, can I cancel within 24 hours?

Comment: "cancel within 24 hours" : do you mean 24 hours after the booking, or 24 hours before your flight/hotel starts?

Comment: This will differ for each ticket/deal.

Comment: Its a federal rule!! Sources:
http://www.dot.gov/airconsumer/notice-24hour-reservation           and                        
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/01/05/how-to-cancel-your-flight_n_6029618.html

Comment: Still I wanna make sure I can do it.

Comment: The federal law applies to airlines, Expedia is a travel agency, hence they can impose "service" charges of their own.  You have to read the rules for the booking you made.

Comment: What do the terms and conditions of Expedia say?

Answer (score 2):

I have traveled on an Expedia bargain fare.  I booked it on the UK site, and my experience relates only to the UK site. This was 3 years ago, and I can't find the e ticket, so some of this is from memory.

I booked a bargain fare from LON (London - all airports) to BOS (Boston Logan airport) return, with a potential of 1 stopover. The deal was approx £200 discount of the cheapest flight I could find, which was with Iceland air.

The fare rules were none transferable, and a cancellation fee of 100% of the fare.

The website stated that the flight(s)  would depart between 6am and 6pm.

I expected to end up either with a regional flight to Europe then onwards to Boston, or possibly a flight to Newark with a connection onwards fron there.

I booked and was pleasantly surprised to get direct flights from Lhr (Heathrow) to Boston with American Airlines.

So the booking conditions that I was under meant that yes I could cancel, but I would lose all the money.

I tried pulling up terms and condition on Expedia both US and UK, and failed, however did find a very dated (2001!) link to a different forum site with Expedia bargain fares info.

http://www.disboards.com/threads/a-tutorial-on-expedia-bargain-fares.43772/

Below is a screen grab of part of that, I suspect it relates to Expedia US

[image]

I hope this answers your query